# Boot ASUS x551m w/Esc or F2 still boots to Windows logon

Tags: boot, bios

Got this ASUSx551m from a friend who unfortunately can't recall the password and it boots to Windows even from a Power off w/F2 or Esc state.  I want to disable Secure Boot and update the Bios but I can't seem to get into the BIOS.  I've tried all recommended suggestions but none allow me access to the Bios.

Comment: If the password could be cleared easily it wouldn't be much security. The very thing you want in a BIOS password also makes it difficult for you to remove it now.

Comment: Also, saying you tried all recommended solutions doesn't help us. Tell us specifically and completely everything that you have tried so we know what not to suggest. Also, there's a lot of questions on this site about this sort of thing. Which of those have you tried?